# Storing outputs of a function based on an interactive argument value

Tags: python, interactive, ipywidgets, holoviews

What I'm trying to do is the following. I have some function f(m) that I want to explore interactively for different values of m (for example using ipywidgets). For specific values of m, I'd like to store some string containing for example m in a list. However, I don't know beforehand which values those will be; I want to plot f(m), and if I like the result, either choose something like True or False, or select Reject or Approve from a dropdown list, and only then have the value be stored. Clicking A or R on the keyboard would also be fine. Is this something I can do? The best I could come up with was using something like ipywidgets:

```
%matplotlib inline
from ipywidgets import interactive
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def f(m):
    plt.figure(2)
    x = np.linspace(-10, 10, num=1000)
    ID = str(m)
    plt.plot(x, m * x)
    plt.ylim(-5, 5)
    plt.show()

interactive_plot = interactive(f, m=(-2.0, 2.0))
output = interactive_plot.children[-1]
output.layout.height = '350px'
interactive_plot
```

In this case, `ID` is the object I would like to store. I could add an extra argument `evaluation` which is either `Accept` or `Reject` or something like that, and add an if statement to the function that appends a list of values, but that seems like a poor choice. Because changing m won't change the value of evaluation, so varying m would just add the ID to the list for every m as long as `evaluation` is set to `Accept`. So then for every value I'd need to set `evaluation` to `Accept` or `Reject`, and then set it back to some value that doesn't do anything like `Undetermined`, which is a lot of clicks. I am sure there would be a better way of doing so; could someone point me in that direction?

Answer (score 0):

This example is probably overkill for your purposes, but it shows how to use Panel (panel.pyviz.org) to save a set of currently chosen widget values (to a file, in this case): https://anaconda.org/jbednar/datashaderattractors/notebook